# ZFS with L2ARC use and reliability

Tags: server, 15.10, raid, nas, zfs

I am planning/building an ubuntu server 15.10 which will primarily be used for a NAS. I opted for Ubuntu Server over the likes of FreeNas as in the future I'll be able to use other features and expandability that FreeNas doesn't have. (eg web server and VM Server)

I will be running the OS boot drive separate to my drive array which will be constructed of 3 x WD Red drives in RAIDz1.

There is a spare MLC SSD laying around from a previous build, barely used, I was considering using it for L2ARC cache just because why not. However I am unsure what are the consequences of the SSD dying in relation to the greater array, will it just default back to the speed of the pool or will it render the entire pool useless?

Answer (score 1):

An L2ARC failure shouldn't affect a ZFS pool content.

All data read from the L2ARC is checksummed so in case of any invalid data or missing data, ZFS fall back to retrieving the data on disk blocks.

However, depending on the kind of failure and the times spent by the drivers or the hardware to assert there is actually a failure, there might be a significant time lost.

Comment: Time loss as in downtime? Which in an enterprise case isn't cool, but in a home use not so bad:
Turn off, unplug SSD, reboot. Acceptable for me.

How about a zil or slog drive though?

Comment: Enterprise class hardware should be quicker to detect a device/hba failure. No need to reboot, removing a faulty (or no faulty) L2ARC device can be done online.